# Dax Returning rows that don't fit filter

Tags: powerbi, dax, power-automate

I've got this code that should query a Power BI Dataset, and return the values that occur twice or more in the past year. However, it seems to be returning values that are within the last year, however, don't occur twice or more. I've verified it by taking the result into Excel and highlighting all duplicates in the Plant No field and there are ( of ~2500 results, maybe 50 are duplicates)

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'WO',
        "Raised Date", 'WO'[Raised Date],
        "Address", 'WO'[WO Address],
        "Plant No", 'WO'[Plant No],
        "Work Order", 'WO'[WO]
    ),
    (
        (COUNT('WO'[Plant No]) >= 2 &&
        'WO'[Raised Date] >= NOW() - 365 &&
        'WO'[Raised Date] <= NOW() + TIME(10, 0, 0))
       
    )
)
```

There are a few more filters that I need but for simplicity sake, I've left this one.

Anyone have any ideas, GPT seems to want to do a Count Rows on a filter but I don't see how that would work.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution that restricts the result to a count > 1 based on the EARLIER function. A performance problem might arise because the filter must be re-computed row by row. It would be better to create a table variable at the beginning containing the plant no along with its count one time and compare it row by row. Addionally you could wrap the result into a SUMMARIZE in order to "remove" the count information.

```
FILTER(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Wo', 
        "Raised Date", 'WO'[Raised Date],
        "Address",     'WO'[WO Address],
        "Plant No",    'WO'[Plant No],
        "Work Order",  'WO'[WO]
        "Count Wo", 
            COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(
                    ALL('Wo'), 
                    'WO'[Plant No] = EARLIER('WO'[Plant No])))), 
    [Count Wo] >= 1 
        && 'WO'[Raised Date] >= NOW() - 365 
        && 'WO'[Raised Date] <= NOW() + TIME(10, 0, 0))
```